# How to find out what is the Query made by drupal solr module

Tags: drupal, solr

I am unable to understand which folder is the logs for the drupal solr integration module. I am using drupal 7 and the module version is 7.x-1.1

I have the solr attachments module as well.

How do i know what is the request that is made when search results are displayed and how can i customize them ? Pls guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place to look for customization of the query that is sent to Solr from Drupal is the api doc (included with the module and available online [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/apachesolr.api.php)).  The hook you will want to look at is [hook_apachesolr_query_alter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/apachesolr.api.php#l191).  It allows you to take a query that has been generated by the module and modify it before it is sent to Solr.

There is no log file generated by the Drupal module (other than watchdog messages), but you can enable logging in the Solr admin interface.  There are also a few ways to enable logging in Solr (see [here](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Configuring+Logging) and [here](http://skybert.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/how-to-get-solr-to-log-to-a-log-file/) for examples). [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LoggingInDefaultJettySetup) are some specific instructions from the Solr wiki on logging using the default Jetty container. I guess the logging settings you use depends on what you are looking for.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Drupal specifics but for SOLR you should look for a "catalina.txt" log file or something similar.

EDIT: It is "catalina.2013-03-31.log" to be more exact.
You are looking for something like this:

```
INFO: [catalog] webapp=/solr path=/select params={sort=startdate+asc&q=(((((_lang:en\-gb+AND)))+AND+startdate:[0001-01-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2013-02-18T00:01:17Z])+AND+enddate:[2013-02-18T00:01:17Z+TO+9999-12-31T23:59:59Z])} hits=6 status=0 QTime=0 
Feb 18, 2013 12:01:38 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
```

What you have after the "&q=" will be the SOLR search query.

Comment: I should have mentioned this but i am running solr from the example dir and therefore the servlet container is jetty embedded within solr. Any idea for this ?

Comment: Do you have access to the file system and to the folders where SOLR is deployed?

Comment: Yeah i do have access to the file system.